# Java: Creating an object, specified by a variable

Tags: java, object

Heythere,
im pretty sure it is not possible, but can you do something like this:

```
var a=emeny.class
new a();
```

*EDIT: Pseudocode; I wanted to store the class in a variable and create an object of the variable somehow.*

i would like to write a method similar to this:?

```
public void spawn(class c){
      addObject(new c(),x,y); 
}
```

in order to later call it with diferent parameters like:

```
spawn(ant);
spawn(fly);
spawn(bee);
```

Is it possible or do i have to use an if statement?

Thanks in advance, 
Jandermannderkann

Comment: Is your code Java or Javascript as u r using var ?

Comment: I'm honestly not really sure what you are trying to do. But maybe you want to do something involving Reflection?

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: the question is correctly tagged java. the first codeblock is just exemplary pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, you can do this by using **Reflection**:

> Reflection is commonly used by programs which require the ability to
>   examine or modify the runtime behavior of applications running in the
>   Java virtual machine.

For example:

```
    try {
        addObject(c.newInstance(),x,y);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For more about reflection, you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to write a method similar to this ?

You can use polymorphism (different forms/types) in Java to pass different types to `spawn()` method and achieve something similar to your code. You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) more polymorphism.

**(1) Define Base Type (Interface)**

```
public interface Insect {
     public void add(int x, int y);
   }
```

**(2) Define Concrete Types (Implementation Classes)**

```
public class Ant implements Insect {
        public void add(int x, int y) {
         //code
        }
    }


public class Bee implements Insect {
    public void add(int x, int y) {
     //code
    }
}

public class Fly implements Insect {
    public void add(int x, int y) {
     //code
    }
}
```

**(3) Create a spawn() to take Base Type:**

```
public class Test {
       public void spawn(Insect insect){

          //calls add method of either Bee or Fly or Ant Type
          //Depends upon the insect object passed to this method
          insect.add(x,y); 
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test test = new Test();

            Bee bee = new Bee();
            Fly fly = new Fly();

            //you can pass either bee or fly objects to your spawn
            test.spawn(bee);
            test.spawn(fly);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object instantiate(Class<?> a)
{
    try {
        return a.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        //if your code ends up here it means there were a problem about instantiation

    } 

    return null;

}
```

However, I recommend you to learn more about basics before this.